# Using same translation for field in views and forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'd like to use same translation for field in views and forms in Rails 4 so I've read the doc (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views) and went through some try and fail then I came to this solution:

config/locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  save: "Save"
  customers:
      description: "Company full legal name"
```

app/views/customers/_form.html.erb:

```
...
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description, (I18n.t :description, scope: :customers) %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>
...
```

app/views/customers/show.html.erb:

```
...
<p>
  <strong><%=t :description, scope: :customers %></strong>
  <%= @customer.description %>
</p>
...
```

But it feels a bit "weird" at least for the part of specifying the scope that I'd expect to be something that Rails does by itself.

One first attempt was to put this in config/locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  helpers:
    label:
      customer:
        description: "Company full legal name"
```

and this in app/views/customers/_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
```

but there was no way of fetching that label for the show view.

Feels like I didn't get from the docs something at the base of the translation system, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by this? "but there was no way of fetching that label for the show view."  What is the error or problem you observe?

Comment: I don't know how to fetch the helper description

Comment: Using i18n takes practice and keen attention paid to runtime context. I recommend installing (temporarily) a gem called i18n-tasks https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-tasks/versions/0.9.2 -- It is a command line tool that will help understand the necessary structure for your apps localization strings in the YAML(s). Once you know where i18n is looking for the string, based on context, you can then put the strings in the right structure in the right order in your YAML.

Comment: Thanks Val, this gem is very useful

Comment: You/re very welcome. I'm glad it helped. Should it be an answer so if others search and find this question they're more likely to find the gem info?

Comment: Yes I think it should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using i18n takes practice and keen attention paid to runtime context.**

I recommend installing (temporarily) a gem called [i18n-tasks](https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-tasks/versions/0.9.2)  -- It is a command line tool that will help understand the necessary structure for your apps localization strings in the YAML(s).

Once you know where i18n is looking for the string, based on context, you can then put the strings in the right structure in the right order in your YAML.